# Language to use with IP address

Tags: ip-address

What language should be used regarding IP address? Does an IP address

- link to
- represent
- identify
- locate

a host?

Comment: Hello, please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask:)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming or software development.

Comment: I don't understand why people are directing me to the 'how to ask page'. My question is quite brief, but I don't see a huge problem with how it's written. If it's about the use of quotes, are bullet points an option? Is this the wrong site for this question?

Comment: Hi Dimpl, I think you should read [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) from the Help Center. [so] is for questions about programming or programmer tools, and your question is about neither. Therefore, your question is off-topic. I suggest you to try [another Stack Exchange site](http://stackexchange.com/sites). However, please read their respective help centers before posting a new question there, and improve your question as much as you can. Good luck.

Comment: Could be a candidate for [superuser](http://superuser.com/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What language should be used regarding IP address?

> Does an IP address ____ a host?

**Identify** would be the correct word to use.

> An IP address, or simply an "IP," is a unique address that **identifies** a device on the Internet or a local network. It allows a system to be recognized by other systems connected via the Internet protocol. There are two primary types of IP address formats used today — IPv4 and IPv6.

Source [IP Address](http://techterms.com/definition/ipaddress)